# Zero Volt reading when motorcycle is running?

Tags: voltage

On a Suzuki gs 550 motorcycle battery reads 12.6 Volts DC when the motor is off. But when I start the motor, digital voltmeter reads zero. I have never seen this before. Any ideas?

Comment: Reads where, measured how, at what exact condition? When it is driving a load voltage drops

Comment: Are you sure you are reading the voltage across the battery terminals? It sounds like a measurement problem.

Comment: what @PlasmaHH said is right.Without knowing the exact way you are measuring we can't say for sure. Also, zero volts means a dead short which sounds kinda impossible in your case.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

You probably measured the voltage across a switch as shown in (a).

- When the switch is open you get full battery voltage reading.
- When the switch is closed the meter is shorted out so you get a zero reading.

Try measuring as shown in (b).